# Do I have to remove a selectedIndexChange event from a listBox when refreshing the data in it?

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, events

I have a listbox in which a have a series of cases retrieved from a database. When i create a new case i wan't to update the listBox to reflect the actual state of the cases-table in the database. But I get a NullReferenceException from the event handler for this line: `populateBoxes((int)lb.SelectedValue)` when i try to update it.

This is my event-handler on the listbox:

```
private void lbCases_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = (ListBox)sender;

            populateBoxes((int)lb.SelectedValue);
        }
```

The update event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.casesTableAdapter.Fill(this.caseDB.cases);

        }
```

I've used the built-in feature of VSE2008 to set the datasource, displaymember and valuemember of the listbox.

Comment: What happens in populateBoxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that when the datasource is set the lbCases_SelectedIndexChanged either does not fire or ignores the event.

Either create a 'Loading' boolean to ignore the event or set the index to -1 and add a check in lbCases_SelectedIndexChanged for the -1 index value to prevent the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Set the selectedindex to -1 and then populate the list box over.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest, you do a check in that event handler:

```
    private void lbCases_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
        if(lb == null)
            return;

        populateBoxes((int)lb.SelectedValue);
    }
```

Comment: @Daniel - apparently the listbox is not null, because i still get the same exception.

Comment: What is the exact stack trace of the exception?

Comment: > caseHandler.exe!caseHandler.caseControl.lbCases_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender = {SelectedItem = ""}, System.EventArgs e = {System.EventArgs}) Line 93 C#

Comment: @Daniel - whoops.. i thought it was. What is a stack trace then?

Comment: For example the result of exception.ToString() contains a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Check the SelectedValue for null before you run the

```
if (lb.SelectedValue != null)
{
    populateBoxes((int)lb.SelectedValue);
}
```

Also, if you want to end up with a selected value, you will have to select it after you call:

```
this.casesTableAdapter.Fill(this.caseDB.cases);
```